# Python Pandas: How to make a column row dependent on it's previous rows, possibly with a function?

Tags: python, function, pandas, rows

I am trying to calculate column B in dependence of previous data of Column A and B. A simple function example would be

e.g. *B(n) = A(n-1) + B(n-1)*,

where *n* is the index of the Pandas dataframe. I do not need necessarily to use the dataframe index.

In this example, I start with B(1) = 0 and add the A rows in consecutive fashion.

```
n    A(n)   B(n)
----------------
1     1      0
2     0      1
3     2      1
4     9      3
```

An example of this data structure would be defined in Pandas as

```
d = {'A' : pd.Series([1, 0, 2, 9],),
     'B' : pd.Series([0, float("nan"), float("nan"), float("nan")])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

---

**Update**

Both Henry Cutchers' and Jakob's answer work well.

Comment: Yeah, that's because it was too late when i posted that -- fixing now... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your example problem can be reduced to be dependent on *B[0]* and *A[n]* only:
[image]
a possible simple solution could look like

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'A' : pd.Series([1, 0, 2, 9],),
     'B' : pd.Series([0, float("nan"), float("nan"), float("nan")])}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
for i in range(1,len(df.A)):
    df.B[i] = df.B[0] + np.sum(df.A[:i])
df
```

which results in the data frame
[image]

If you face a similar iterative dependency you should be able to construct a similar approach suiting your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about using Cython http://www.cython.org ?  It will interoperate with pandas -- same data structures, etc (as pandas is written in cython).  It looks to me like you'll need the ability to iterate across your dataframe in arbitrary ways (not knowing more about your problem, that's all I can say), and yet need speed.  Cython compiles to C.

I could forsee a loop of the form:

```
import numpy
import pandas
import datetime
dates = pandas.date_range('20130101',periods=6)
myDataFrame = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.arange(12).reshape((6,2)),index=dates,columns=list('ab'))
a=myDataFrame["a"]
b=myDataFrame["b"]
print a
print b
out=numpy.empty_like(a.values)
out[0] = 0
#this loop will work but be slow...
for i in range(1, a.shape[0]):
    out[i] = a[i-1] + b[i-1]
myDataFrame['c'] = pandas.Series(out, index=myDataFrame.index)
print myDataFrame
```

But that's going to be slow.

Comment: Hello Henry, indeed it is the freedom of ways of iteration you mentioned I want to use. At this moment performance is of secondary concern to me. So far it is unclear to me how I should accomplish this in Python/Pandas.

Comment: You had a *SyntaxError: invalid syntax* in *out=np.empty(shape=(a.shape[0],),dtype=np.float32))*. Right now, I get an array for **out** that looks like this: 

Out[13]:

*array([ nan,   1.,  nan,  nan], dtype=float32*

Comment: Fixed by program to actually run :-)

Comment: Hi, I am accepted the above answer, since it was more straighforward to implement. However, I would like to vote you up once I have the required reputation to do so. Thanks for you help!